# Android Studio Arctic Fox doesn't recognise Java imports in a Kotlin module (non Android) on Mac with M1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

When I create a pure Kotlin Library module in Android Studio on Macbook Pro with M1, AS doesn’t recognize Java dependencies. Everything builds fine.

Everything also works fine when I change this module into Android Library.

I tried a few different Java implementations and it doesn’t help.
I also tried to use different versions of Android Studio - stable, beta.
Finally it works in Android Studio Chipmunk (canary version).

Any other solution than using Canary version of AS?

I've created a bug on Google Issuetracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208860817

[image]

Comment: Happens to me as well. Latest stable intellij idea CE (2021.3) works fine.

Comment: It works also in Android Studio Chipmunk, based on Intellij (2021.2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Android Studio Chipmunk, based on Intellij (2021.2.1).
AS Team won't fix it in any previous version.